# pyuic4 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: pyqt4

i am new to python programming specially the GUI.i am designing the GUI for my project using QT designer(pyqt4).when ever i try to convert the .ui file to the python code using pyuic4 it gives me the segmentation fault error i am not able to figure out  the reason.

[image: here is the Screenshot]

Comment: How have you installed pyqt4?

Comment: yes i have installed it using "apt-cache search pyqt "," sudo apt-get install python-qt4"

Answer (score 0):

1. First try to import Qt module from PyQt4

   ```
   >>>from PyQt4 import Qt
   ```

If this gives segment fault then follow next step

2. Please do check for the SIP version

   ```
   >>>import sip
   >>>print sip.SIP_VERSION_STR
   ```

It should be 4.18 or later version

3. If not then uninstall PyQt4, update/install SIP. After this install PyQt4(order is important: first SIP then PyQt) and try to import Qt again. Hope it should not give error.

PS: I had same error and above steps worked!! I use python v3.6.